# Data Validation based on Condition(s) in Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I was wondering if it is possible to only show items in a data validation list based on condition(s)?

Like for example, if I input AAA on cell A1, the data validation list in cll B1 will only show what's on its adjacent cells for example 1,2,3 or if I input BBB on cell A1, the data validation list in cell B1 will only show what's on its adjacent cells for example 4,5,6?

The catch here is the strings that are being written in cell A1 is dynamic. Like for example today I have 50 options to put in cell A1 all of which have their own named ranges to show in the data validation list in cell B1, then tomorrow it can only have 20 options.

Also, the number of items in those named ranges vary as well.

Any ideas?

Thank you

I also posted here where I am able to attach a sample file: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?67237-Data-Validation-based-on-Condition(s)-in-Excel-VBA&p=401358#post401358

for example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBYYQ.png[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBYYQ.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBYYQ.png):

Comment: Hi @Jazz H ,,, [Check this link, recently I've solves similar issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1542550/data-validation-based-on-another-cell-and-two-column/1542769#1542769) ☺

Comment: Is this solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula as a named range, you can type the search term in E3 it will identify the range in the A column containing the entered text (eg A10:A15 contain AAA) and will return the matching range in the B column (eg: B10:B15).

```
=INDIRECT("$B$"&MATCH($E$3,INDIRECT("$A$1:$A$"& COUNTA($A:$A)),FALSE)&":$B$"& MATCH($E$3,INDIRECT("$A$1:$A$"& COUNTA($A:$A)),FALSE) + COUNTIF(INDIRECT("$A$1:$A$"& COUNTA($A:$A)),$E$3)-1)
```

Once you have put the formula in as a named range use the list function in "DATA VALIDATION" to refer to the named range.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, This worked perfectly! Thank you so much! However I have another question. my cell E3 also has a data validation. Like the list of categories. The problem with is that if I base that data validation on the list I attached here (the picture), it's showing duplicate values. Like if there are 3 sub categories for the category, there will be 3 categories on cell E3 to choose from. How do I remove the duplicates without affecting the cell validation on cell C3?

Comment: Hi Jazz, If it worked perfect just tick it off as solved and post another question with some detail of the new problem.